# Why is my program not counting word hello when it reads from a text file in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to java and coding in general and I was learning how to read from file. I have looked up at the process on how to add file into the src folder by just dragging it but my question persists on why my program is not counting a string "hello" when it reads the file successfully. According to what I think, it is the first element that shows us and I have used the IF statement to check out by storing it in a string element line. can someone explain this to me in a beginner friendly way.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File path = new File("C:\\Users\\fahad\\IdeaProjects\\testingFileIO\\src\com\\Fahad\\Readingfile.txt");
        Scanner fileread = new Scanner(path);
        String check = "hello";
        int count=0;

        boolean flag = false;
        while(fileread.hasNextLine()){
            String line = fileread.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            if(line == check)
            {
                flag = true;
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(flag == true)
        {
            System.out.println("WE found it" + count);
        }
        else
        {
            Syste.out.println("No string was there");
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
hello world.
This is fahad Qazi
How are you doing ?
checking
1234567
No string was there
```

I am new to stackoverflow so sorry about this question but any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to use String#equals() to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of your code is alright. It can be better, but it's alright for a start.
As to where you're going wrong is the line:

```
if (line == check)
```

You're comparing the complete line if it equals to the string `"hello"`. This returns `false` since the line in question is `hello world`.

A solution to this is to do a [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) operations. Below is an example of this

```
String myStr = "Hello world";
System.out.println(myStr.contains("Hello"));   // true
System.out.println(myStr.contains("world"));   // true
System.out.println(myStr.contains("hello"));   // false due to case sensitivity
System.out.println(myStr.contains("Hi"));      // false
```

So in your case you should check the following using contains:

```
if (line.contains(check)) // do the things you wanna do when the line contains 'hello'
```

Comment: If this answer was the thing you're looking for @faded feel free to also mark this as a solution. This helps the community to easily find the answers to questions.

Comment: Thank you. yes efficiency is the best when you code but trial and error answers my curiosity,.

Answer (score 0):

To compare String values you don't have to use **"=="**.

You have to compare with the equals method from String class.
For example:

```
String x="hello",y="world";
if(x.equals(y)){

}
```

Or you can use `x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)` if you want to compare two strings and ignore uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: i tried the recommendation and input line.equals(check) but still it is giving me the boolean value false and not catching hello.

Comment: I see the error, you are comparing the full line:
The first one returns **"hello world"**, so the code is comparing if check is equals to **"hello world"**. 
To can compare correctly you should split your line by spaces, with the split method.
Your code must be like this:
`String words[] = line.split(" ");` //_or you can use regex here_
`for(String words : words){`
  `if(word.equals(check)) { ... }`
`}`

Comment: Thank you for clarifiying but what is Regex as you mentioned in second part of answer. Also creating a string of words what is going on there ? like creating an array that contains the space or does it take everything from the file and spaces or moves an index after it has reacher "  " ?? Thank you again

Comment: @Faded the **regex (regular expressions)** are used for input/string validation. You can read about regex (specially in java) in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm
Then, if you have the next string: `Hello world`,  you can see there is a space between **Hello** and *world*, so, if you use `line.split(" ")` , that will return a string array like this: `{ "Hello", "World" }`.

Comment: As you can see,the space was removed in that string. But if your string were `Hello  World` (with 2 spaces) the `line.split(" ")` will return `{ "Hello", "","World"}`. Now, you can see the array contains an empty string: "". So, the solution is use a regex, you can try something like this: `line.split("\\s+")` , where **\\s** represent a space in regex, and **+** represents that the last pattern (in this case \\s or space) repeats one or more times.

Answer (score 0):

Direct `==` operation on string will not work. You need to use `contains(CharSequence s)` method from `String` class in-order to check if the the required sequence of characters is present in the given string or not. You need to make use of this method in your code in order to achieve the required result.

Additionally, if you are using Java 8+, then solution can be simplified/re-written as:

```
long count = Files.lines(Paths.get(<your_file_path>))
.filter(line -> line.contains(check))
.count();
```

Comment: For starters i'd instead solve the problem first with the code he has. Then later refactor it. Saying using a oneliner without any other given info won't help him much to become a better coder.

Comment: @Baklap4 Thanks for pointing out and I totally agree to it. Will keep this in mind for all my future answers. Made edits in order to help OP better understand the concept.

Comment: and @ShyamBaitmangalkar, it is indeed helpful to know more about such codes. As such i tend to draw them in a book to understand what is going on in here. For your code mentioned above. It seems like you are assigning directly the variable count  to lines ?? or to a path ?? second once is like a method/Function that will filter out the word i need i suppose.

Comment: @Faded `Paths.get("<file_path>")` will give an object of type `Path`. `Files.lines()` take a path object and returns a `Stream<String>` from the given File. Once you have a `Stream<String>` you can perform streaming operations on it to arrive at the required result.